# What advantages does a Document-based database have over a Relational database?

Tags: sql-server, couchdb

For example: Microsoft SQL Server vs. CouchDB.

The main benefit for me with CouchDB is that you can access it from pretty much **anywhere!** What advantages does a document based database have over a relational one?

Where would a document based db be a better choice over a relational?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say "accessing it from anywhere" is an advantage of CouchDB over SQL Server.  Both are fully accessible from a variety of clients.

The key differentiating factor is the fundamental concept of how data is persisted as tables & columns (SQL Server) versus documents (CouchDB).  In addition, CouchDB is designed to leverage multiple copies with replication/map-reduce in a highly forgiving fashion.  SQL Server can do the same level of fault tolerance but true map-reduce is non-existant in it (it's ability to deal with sets mimics the capabilities fundamentally however - see GROUPING SETS keyword).

You should note this post which really shows that map reduce has its place, but you need to pick the right tool for the job:

http://gigaom.com/2009/04/14/mapreduce-vs-sql-its-not-one-or-the-other/